# Метод equals() в kotlin.text.Char.kt

Tags: kotlin, char, equals

В файле [Char.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/Char.kt) пакета *kotlin.text* есть следующий метод `equals()`:

```
public fun Char.equals(other: Char, ignoreCase: Boolean = false): Boolean {
    if (this == other) return true
    if (!ignoreCase) return false

    if (this.toUpperCase() == other.toUpperCase()) return true
    if (this.toLowerCase() == other.toLowerCase()) return true
    return false
}
```

И я не совсем понимаю, зачем нужна строка с `toLowerCase()`...
В каких случаях после того, как сравнение

```
if (this.toUpperCase() == other.toUpperCase())
```

вернёт `false`, сравнение

```
if (this.toLowerCase() == other.toLowerCase())
```

может вернуть `true`?

Comment: я слышал что-то про турецкую i у которой несколько вариантов в верхнем регистре

Comment: Это связано с локализацией: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063102/using-locales-with-javas-tolowercase-and-touppercase

Comment: Разные коды символа в `unicode` таблице.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Из стандарта Юникод](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Simple_Loose_Matches):

> In addition, because of the vagaries of natural language, there are situations where two different Unicode characters have the same uppercase or lowercase. ... For example, the Greek U+03C3 "σ" small sigma, U+03C2 "ς" small final sigma, and U+03A3 "Σ" capital sigma all match.
>
> *Также, из-за особенностей естественных языков возникают ситуации когда два разных символа Юникод соответствуют одному и тому же символу в верхнем или нижнем регистре. ... Например, греческие буквы U+03C3 "σ" (прописная сигма), U+03C2 "ς" (прописная сигма в конце слова), и U+03A3 "Σ" (заглавная сигма) все совпадают [при сравнении без учета регистра].*

Также для примера можно привести символы `I` (латинская заглавная I) и `İ` (латинская заглавная I с точкой). Оба символа в верхнем регистре, но оба соответствуют одному и тому же символу в нижнем регистре, соответственно при сравнении без учета регистра должны считаться одинаковыми.

```
val a = 'I'
val b = 'İ'
System.out.println(a==b) //false
System.out.println(a.toUpperCase()==b.toUpperCase()) //false
System.out.println(a.toLowerCase()==b.toLowerCase()) //true
System.out.println(a.equals(b, true)) //true
```

Похожий вопрос на английском и по Java: [Understanding logic in CaseInsensitiveComparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518731/understanding-logic-in-caseinsensitivecomparator/).

Код, который генерирует совпадающие пары: https://ideone.com/a8scLw

P.S. Реализация `equals` использует упрощенный вариант сравнения. Для полноты нужно сравнивать не только соответствующие символы, но и соответствующие соответствующим. Например, для `İ` и `ı` метод вернет false, хотя оба они считаются равными `I`.

```
System.out.println('İ'.equals('I', true)) //true
System.out.println('I'.equals('ı', true)) //true
System.out.println('İ'.equals('ı', true)) //false
```